# Pandas corrupting datetime object

Tags: python, pandas, datetime, pytz

I am trying to create timezone aware date column in a pandas DataFrame. When I run the code below, the resulting pandas column does not have the same datetime as the one I inputted.  What am I doing wrong here?

I am using python 3.6.2 and pandas 0.20.3

```
from datetime import datetime
import pandas as pd
import pytz 
date_string = "12/14/2016 12:00"
timezone = pytz.timezone("US/Pacific")
input_datetime =  datetime.strptime(date_string, "%m/%d/%Y %H:%M").replace(tzinfo=timezone)
df = pd.DataFrame({"datetime":[input_datetime]})
```

If I run that code, `df['datetime'][0].minute` returns `53` while `input_datetime.minute` returns `0`.

When I don't replace the tzinfo I do not have a problem.

Comment: Post your actual code, not a screenshot. Also take a look at [this link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20109391/how-to-make-good-reproducible-pandas-examples).

Comment: What do you mean by changing?  Is it because you are calling minutes of `x` which is `10/5/16 0:00`?

Comment: @JosephK. `datetime.datetime(2016, 12, 14, 12, 0, tzinfo=<DstTzInfo 'US/Pacific' LMT-1 day, 16:07:00 STD>)` becomes `Timestamp('2016-12-14 11:53:00-0800', tz='US/Pacific')` after I create the pandas DataFrame

Answer (score 1):

If you first convert your `input_datetime` you can call the minutes (or years etc) of your dataframe with `.dt.minute`

```
input_datetime = pd.to_datetime(datetime.strptime(date_string, 
                                                  "%m/%d/%Y %H:%M")).replace(tzinfo=timezone)


df = pd.DataFrame({"datetime":[input_datetime]})
df['datetime'].dt.minute
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use pandas `.dt` and `tz_localize`:

```
from datetime import datetime
import pandas as pd
date_string = "12/14/2016 12:00"
df = pd.DataFrame({'datetime':[datetime.strptime(date_string, "%m/%d/%Y %H:%M")]})
df['datetime'].dt.tz_localize('US/Pacific')
```

Output:

```
0   2016-12-14 12:00:00-08:00
Name: datetime, dtype: datetime64[ns, US/Pacific]
```